# Creating the maximum possible decimal number from a given number of max digits and decimal places in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given `max_digits` and `decimal_places`, the method will return the maximum possible decimal number. The following is my code right now:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def get_max_decimal_number(max_digits, decimal_places):
    result = ''

    for i in range(max_digits - decimal_places):
        result += '9'

    if decimal_places > 0:
        result += '.'
        for i in range(decimal_places):
            result += '9'

    return Decimal(result)
```

No type checks are done because we make the following assumptions:

- `max_digits` is an integer greater than or equal to 1.
- `decimal_places` is an integer greater than or equal to 0, and less than or equal to the `max_digits`.

The results are as follows:

```
>>> get_max_decimal_number(4, 2)
Decimal('99.99')
>>> get_max_decimal_number(2, 2)
Decimal('0.99')
>>> get_max_decimal_number(1, 0)
Decimal('9')
```

You can test it out [here](https://repl.it/repls/RingedTrustingShareware)

My solution right now feels a bit hacky. Is there a better way to do this? Maybe some built in method that I'm not aware of.

Comment: What is the objective here? How do you want to use this?

Comment: @EchoCloud Does it matter?

Comment: Just a note that this type of question, where your code works but you want to improve it, is perfect for the [codereview.se] stack site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
def get_max_decimal_number(max_digits, decimal_places):
  return float('9'*(max_digits-decimal_places)+'.'+'9'*decimal_places)

print(get_max_decimal_number(2,2)) # outputs 0.99

print(get_max_decimal_number(4, 2)) # outputs 99.99

print(get_max_decimal_number(1, 0)) # outputs 9.0
```

See it in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/EvergreenPeskyJavadocs)

You may use [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) instead of `float` to type cast the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
from decimal import Decimal

def get_max_decimal_number(max_digits, decimal_places):
    return Decimal('9' * (max_digits - decimal_places) + '.' + '9' * decimal_places)
```